# The '?' modifier can only be used in TypeScript files. Typescript error . "?" operator error

Tags: reactjs, next.js

What's this error about ?? Next js.

```
  error - ./components/MiniProfile.js
Error: 
      x An object member cannot be declared optional
       ,----
     9 | { session? (
       :          ^
       `----
    
      x Unexpected token `(`. Expected ... , *,  (, [, :, , ?, = or an identifier
       ,----
     9 | { session? (
       :            ^
       `----
    
    Caused by:
        0: failed to process input file
        1: Syntax Error
```

MiniProfile.js

```
    import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

    function MiniProfile() {
    const { data: session } = useSession()


    return (
        { session?(
            <div>
                <div className="p-4 flex border mt-14 ml-10 items-center 
                justify-between">
                    <img src={session?.user?.image}
                        className="h-16 w-16 rounded-full border p-1 object-cover" />
                    <div className="flex-1 mx-4 ">
                        <h2 className="font-bold">pj</h2>
                        <h3 className="text-sm text-gray-500"> Welcome to Instagram</h3>
                    </div>

                    <button onClick={signOut}
                        className="text-blue-400 text-sm font-semibold">Sign out</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        ) : (<div> hii </div>)}

    )}
export default MiniProfile;
```

Comment: Seems like a syntax error, trying to parse `({ session...` as an object literal. Try something like this instead: `return session ? (<div>...</div>) : (<div>...</div>)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add `{}` after `return` is incorrect, it should have elements before using `{}`.

You also have another problem here `session?`. `session?` means an optional chaining condition which is unexpected in your case. If you want to have the ternary condition, you should add space like `session ?`.

A few examples:

```
return { session ? <div></div> : <div></div> } //wrong
```

```
return session ? <div></div> : <div></div> //correct
```

```
return <React.Fragment>{session ? <div></div> : <div></div>}</React.Fragment> //correct
```

Final formatted code

```
import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react";

function MiniProfile() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  return session ? (
    <div>
      <div
        className="p-4 flex border mt-14 ml-10 items-center 
                justify-between"
      >
        <img
          src={session?.user?.image}
          className="h-16 w-16 rounded-full border p-1 object-cover"
        />
        <div className="flex-1 mx-4 ">
          <h2 className="font-bold">pj</h2>
          <h3 className="text-sm text-gray-500"> Welcome to Instagram</h3>
        </div>

        <button
          onClick={signOut}
          className="text-blue-400 text-sm font-semibold"
        >
          Sign out
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div> hii </div>
  );
}
export default MiniProfile;
```

Comment: yes.. ( return session ? <div></div> : <div></div> //correct ) this helped me. thank you